# Perform a semi-join with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, semi-join

How do I perform a [semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29) with data.table? A semi-join is like an inner join except that it only returns the columns of X (not also those of Y), and does not repeat the rows of X to match the rows of Y.  For example, the following code performs an inner join:

```
x <- data.table(x = 1:2, y = c("a", "b"))
setkey(x, x)
y <- data.table(x = c(1, 1), z = 10:11)

x[y]
#   x y  z
# 1: 1 a 10
# 2: 1 a 11
```

A semi-join would return just `x[1]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

More possibilities :

```
w = unique(x[y,which=TRUE])  # the row numbers in x which have a match from y
x[w]
```

If there are duplicate key values in x, then that needs :

```
w = unique(x[y,which=TRUE,allow.cartesian=TRUE])
x[w]
```

Or, the other way around :

```
setkey(y,x)
w = !is.na(y[x,which=TRUE,mult="first"])
x[w]
```

If nrow(x) << nrow(y) then the y[x] approach should be faster.
If nrow(x) >> nrow(y) then the x[y] approach should be faster.

But the anti anti join appeals too :-)

Comment: Cool! Now I understand what `allow.cartesian=TRUE` is for.

Comment: I knew that guru will stop by! Since you officially liked the anti anti join approach, how about adding `x[!!y]` to the syntax? :)

Comment: @VictorK. :) `x[!!y]` is an error currently isn't it, so ok. Please file as a feature request.

Comment: For what it's worth, the anti-join operation was implemented as `x[!y]` and not the syntax above.

Comment: This solution causes R to crash for me with moderately large data.tables. (x ~ 3 million rows, and y ~ 2,000 rows).  Really wish semi-join operator was implemented as part of the data.table core...

Comment: @Jthorpe Have you searched the issue list to see if it's on the list properly.  If you can provide a reproducible example for your crash then it would really help raise the priority. I suspect that something else is wrong though in your query though. We need to see the output/warnings/verbose to help.

Comment: double anti join: `tmp <- x[!y]; x[!tmp]`?

Answer (score 14):

One solution I can think of is:

```
tmp <- x[!y]
x[!tmp]
```

In `data.table`, you can have another data table as an `i` expression (i.e., the first expression in the `data.table.[` call), and that will perform a join, e.g.:

```
x <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])
setkey(x, x)
y <- data.table(x = c(1,3,5,1), z = 1:4)

> x[y]
   x y z
1: 1 a 1
2: 3 c 2
3: 5 e 3
4: 1 a 4
```

The `!` before the `i` expression is an extension of the syntax above that performs a 'not-join', as described on p. 11 of data.table [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf). So the first assignments evaluates to a subset of `x` that doesn't have any rows where the key (column `x`) is present in `y`:

```
> x[!y]
    x y
1:  2 b
2:  4 d
3:  6 f
4:  7 g
5:  8 h
6:  9 i
7: 10 j
```

It is similar to `setdiff` in this regard. And therefore the second statement returns all the rows in `x` where the key **is** present in `y`.

The `!` feature was added in `data.table 1.8.4` with the following note in [NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/NEWS):

> ```
> o   A new "!" prefix on i signals 'not-join' (a.k.a. 'not-where'), #1384i.
>         DT[-DT["a", which=TRUE, nomatch=0]]   # old not-join idiom, still works
>         DT[!"a"]                              # same result, now preferred.
>         DT[!J(6),...]                         # !J == not-join
>         DT[!2:3,...]                          # ! on all types of i
>         DT[colA!=6L | colB!=23L,...]          # multiple vector scanning approach (slow)
>         DT[!J(6L,23L)]                        # same result, faster binary search
>     '!' has been used rather than '-' :
>         * to match the 'not-join'/'not-where' nomenclature
>         * with '-', DT[-0] would return DT rather than DT[0] and not be backwards
>           compatible. With '!', DT[!0] returns DT both before (since !0 is TRUE in
>           base R) and after this new feature.
>         * to leave DT[+J...] and DT[-J...] available for future use
> ```

For some reason, the following doesn't work `x[!(x[!y])]` - probably `data.table` is too smart about parsing the argument.

P.S. As Josh O'Brien pointed in another answer, a one-line would be `x[!eval(x[!y])]`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how that works? What's the negation of a data table?

Comment: On p.11 [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf), it says `All types of ‘i‘ may be preﬁxed with !. This signals a not-join or not-select should be performed.`

Comment: So you need to know that plus the two advanced notes that follow. I think a full explanation would be a useful addition to your answer.

Comment: @hadley - does it look better now?

Comment: Looks great! Although it seems crazy that to implement a semi-join you do an anti-anti-join ;)

Comment: I know :). Let's wait till @Matthew Dowle comes and enlightens us all.

Comment: Your `x` needs a key, right? It doesn't seem to be set above.

Answer (score 10):

I'm confused with all the not-joins above, isn't what you want simply:

```
unique(x[y, .SD])
#   x y
#1: 1 a
```

If `x` can have duplicate keys, then you can unique `y` instead:

```
## Creating an example data.table 'a' three-times-repeated first row 
x <- data.table(x = c(1,1,1,2), y = c("a", "a", "a", "b"))
setkey(x, x)
y <- data.table(x = c(1, 1), z = 10:11)
setkey(y, x)

x[eval(unique(y, by = key(y))), .SD] # data.table >= 1.9.8 requires by=key(y)
#    x y
# 1: 1 a
# 2: 1 a
# 3: 1 a
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**. Based on all the discussion here, I would do something like this, which should be fast and work in the most general case:

```
x[eval(unique(y[, key(x), with = FALSE]))]
```

---

Here is another, more direct solution:

```
unique(x[eval(y$x)])
```

It's more direct and runs faster - here is the comparison in run times with my previous solution:

```
# Generate some large data
N <- 1000000 * 26
x <- data.table(x = 1:N, y = letters, z = rnorm(N))
setkey(x, x)
y <- data.table(x = sample(N, N/10, replace = TRUE),  z = sample(letters, N/10, replace = TRUE))
setkey(y, x)

system.time(r1 <- x[!eval(x[!y])])
   user  system elapsed 
  7.772   1.217  11.998 

system.time(r2 <- unique(x[eval(y$x)]))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.540   0.142   0.723
```

In a more general case, you can do something like

```
x[eval(y[, key(x), with = FALSE])]
```

Comment: Yes, I've added it above

Comment: If you take unique before joining, it's faster (benchmarked similarly in my answer).

Answer (score 3):

I tried to write a method that doesn't use any names, which are downright confusing in the OP's example.

```
sJ <- function(x,y){
    ycols <- 1:min(ncol(y),length(key(x)))
    yjoin <- unique(y[, ..ycols])
    yjoin
}

x[eval(sJ(x,y))]
```

For Victor's simpler example, this gives the desired output:

```
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 3 c
3: 5 e
```

This is a ~30% slower than Victor's way.

**EDIT:** And Victor's approach, taking unique before joining, is quite a bit faster:

```
N <- 1e5*26
x <- data.table(x = 1:N, y = letters, z = rnorm(N))
setkey(x, x)
y <- data.table(x = sample(N, N/10, replace = TRUE),  z = sample(letters, N/10, replace = TRUE))
setkey(y, x)
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    sJ=x[eval(sJ(x,y))],
    dolla=unique(x[eval(y$x)]),
    brack=x[eval(unique(y[['x']]))]
)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 #    sJ 120.22700 125.04900 126.50704 132.35326 217.6566   100
 # dolla 105.05373 108.33804 109.16249 118.17613 285.9814   100
 # brack  53.95656  61.32669  61.88227  65.21571 235.8048   100
```

I'm guessing the `[[` vs `$` doesn't help the speed, but didn't check.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is so old. But I noticed that the solution can be easily derived from the definition of semi-join given in the original post:

> "A semi-join is like an inner join except that it only returns the
>   columns of X (not also those of Y), and does not repeat the rows of X
>   to match the rows of Y"

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <-  data.table(ProdId = 1:4,
                   Product = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Pizza", "Butter"))
dt2 <-  data.table(ProdId = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5),
                   Company = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

# semi-join
unique(merge(dt1, dt2, on="ProdId")[, names(dt1), with=F])
   ProdId Product
1:      1   Bread
2:      3   Pizza
3:      4  Butter
```

I've simply applied the syntax of inner-join, followed by filtering columns from first table only, with `unique()` to remove rows of first table which were repeated to match rows of second table.

**Edit:** The above approach will match `dplyr::semi_join()` output only if we have unique rows in the first table. If we need to output all the rows including duplicates from first table, then we may use `fsetdiff()` method shown below.

Another one line `data.table` solution:

```
fsetdiff(dt1, dt1[!dt2, on="ProdId"])
   ProdId Product
1:      1   Bread
2:      3   Pizza
3:      4  Butter
```

I've just removed from first table the anti-join of first and second. Seems simpler to me. If the first table has duplicate rows, we will need:

```
fsetdiff(dt1, dt1[!dt2, on="ProdId"], all=T)
```

The `fsetdiff()` result with `,all=T` matches the output from dplyr:

```
dplyr::semi_join(dt1, dt2, by="ProdId")
  ProdId Product
1      1   Bread
2      3   Pizza
3      4  Butter
```

Using another set of data taken from one of previous posts:

```
x <- data.table(x = c(1,1,1,2), y = c("a", "a", "a", "b"))
y <- data.table(x = c(1, 1), z = 10:11)
```

With dplyr:

```
dplyr::semi_join(x, y, by="x")
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 a
```

With data.table:

```
fsetdiff(x, x[!y, on="x"], all=T)
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 1 a
3: 1 a
```

Without `,all=T`, the duplicate rows are removed:

```
fsetdiff(x, x[!y, on="x"])
   x y
1: 1 a
```

Comment: Your first approach runs into the same problems as eddi's first answer when `x` has identical (key) rows.

Comment: I've noticed that it's effectively the same expression. Can you point out cases where the `fsetdiff()` approach will fail?

Comment: Seems like the `fsetdiff` approach also gets rid of duplicate rows in x just like the first approach. Try using the data in eddi's second approach. The result should be 3 rows, but `fsetdiff` only returns 1.

Comment: `fsetdiff(dt1, dt1[!dt2, on="ProdId"], all=T)` will get all the rows. I've updated my post to include both situations.

Comment: The fsetdiff with all=TRUE is a nice variation on Victor's answer, but I still don't find it satisfactory, syntax-wise. There are a couple open requests, fyi: #915 (also linked under Matt's answer) and my https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2158 (that I wrote because I forgot about the first one...)

Comment: @Frank: I agree. `data.table` library should have a **direct** syntax for semi-join instead of users having to "derive" it by using other `data.table` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The package **dplyr** supports the following four join types:

`inner_join`, `left_join`, `semi_join`, `anti_join`

So for the semi-join try the following code

```
library("dplyr")

table1 <- data.table(x = 1:2, y = c("a", "b"))
table2 <- data.table(x = c(1, 1), z = 10:11)

semi_join(table1, table2)
```

The output is as expected:

```
# Joining by: "x"
# Source: local data table [1 x 2]
# 
#       x     y
#   (int) (chr)
# 1     1     a
```

Comment: Yes, I asked the question so I could figure out how to make `semi_join()` work for data tables ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 w <- y[,unique(x)]
 x[x %in% w]
```

Output will be:

```
   x y
1: 1 a
```