# Filtering a data.table using two variables, an elegant fast way

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to ask you if there is a way to filter depending on the combination of more than one variable. To be more specific:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

data <- iris %>% cbind( group = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), nrow(iris))) %>% as.data.table()

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species group
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     a
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     b
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     c
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     a
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     b
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     c
```

and i want to filter them based on the following datatable

```
filter <- data.table(Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", 'setosa'), group = c('a', "b", 'c'))
      Species group      filter1
1:     setosa     a     setosa a
2: versicolor     b versicolor b
3:     setosa     c     setosa c
```

I could do that in that way:

```
data[paste(Species, group) %in% filter[, filter1 := paste(Species, group)]$filter1]
```

However I would like to know if there is  **a way to do it more efficiently/faster/easier** :
something perhaps like:

```
data[.(Species, group) %in% filter] # does not work
```

Comment: @Jaap I guess the link is for a more complicated filtering operation, like `on=.(x = x, y != y)`. Here, I think `data[filter, on=names(filter), nomatch=0]` is probably the target, or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969420/perform-a-semi-join-with-data-table

Comment: Yes, indeed @Frank answers my question and also answers to what I was looking to. Because as I state I was searching a more elegant and easy way to do it. The answer of Frank is sufficient, if you please write it as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can do

```
data[filter, on=names(filter), nomatch=0]
```

See 
[Perform a semi-join with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969420/perform-a-semi-join-with-data-table) for similar filtering joins.