# R data.table group by where

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following in an R data.table:

```
  id | status
=============
   1 |      A
   1 |      B
   2 |      A
   2 |      B
   3 |      A
   4 |      A
   5 |      B
```

I want to show only the rows grouped by id that have an A, but not a B. So a result would be something like this:

```
  id | status
=============
   3 |      A
   4 |      A
```

So far I have this:

```
dt[, sum(status == "A") > 0 && sum(status == "B") == 0, by = id]
```

which gets me:

```
  id | status
=============
   1 |  FALSE
   2 |  FALSE
   3 |   TRUE
   4 |   TRUE
   5 |  FALSE
```

which I think is on the right track, but I don't know how to just get the rows that I want. Am I on the right track, or am I completely thinking about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

In this (I assume simplified) example you can filter the rows that have a `B`, then **anti-join** those back onto the original data

```
dt[ !dt[ status == "B" ], on = "id" ]

#    id status
# 1:  3      A
# 2:  4      A
```

---

This works because

```
dt[ status == "B"]
```

gives the 'id's that have a `B`. These are the ones you want to exclude from your result set, which can be achieved through the anti-join (the `dt[ !dt[ ] on = "" ]` notation)

---

If your data is more complex, you can add some extra filters into this logic to first filter the values you want, e.g.

```
dt[status == "A"][ !dt[ status == "B" ], on = "id" ]
```

will ensure your returned result will include the IDs that have an `A` and not a `B`

Comment: For the last point, to get ids with an A, might need a self semi join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969420/perform-a-semi-join-with-data-table like `dt[dt[status=="A", .(id)], on="id"]` or something.

Comment: @Frank that won't exclude those `A` ids that also have a `B` value ?

Comment: Yes, I meant just the first part of the `dt[...][...]` chain. So with `DT = data.table(id = 1, status = LETTERS[c(1,3)])`, I'd want to see all rows for the `id`, not just the first one, so `DT[.(DT[status == "A", unique(id)]), on="id"][!.(DT[status == "B", unique(id)]), on="id"]` not `DT[status == "A"][!.(DT[status == "B", unique(id)]), on="id"]`