# Extract rows of data.table according to rows of another data.table

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, subset, extract

I couldn't find any answer to this, but I think it's easy to do.

I have this data.table:

```
DT = expand.grid(Season = c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall"),
                 Station = c("A","B","C"),
                 Group = c("1","2","3","4"))
DT$Value = seq(1,length(DT[,1]),1)
DT = data.table(DT)
```

I want to obtain a subset of `DT` according to this other data.table:

```
indexTable = data.table(Season = c("Winter","Spring","Spring"),
                        Station = c("B","B","A"),
                        Group = c("1","2","3"))
```

Basically I want only the rows of `DT` that are contained in `indexTable`. The expected result is this table:

```
expectedTable = data.table(Season = c("Winter","Spring","Spring"),
                           Station = c("B","B","A"),
                           Group = c("1","2","3"),
                           Value = c(5,18,26))
```

I am trying to obtain that with this code:

```
tryTable = DT[DT$Station %in% indexTable$Station &
              DT$Season %in% indexTable$Season &
              DT$Group %in% indexTable$Group,]
```

which gives me not only the 3 rows I want, but also other rows of `DT`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy way to obtain `expectedTable` using data.table indexing notation (for instance using `setkey`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after an INNER JOIN of the two tables.

```
DT[
    indexTable
    , on = c("Season", "Station", "Group")
    , nomatch = 0
]

   Season Station Group Value
1: Winter       B     1     5
2: Spring       B     2    18
3: Spring       A     3    26
```

---

Reference

- [JOINing data in R using data.table](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html)

Comment: If OP wants the subset to retain the row order of DT, then this covers it, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18969420/

Comment: @Frank then let's close as dupe?

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for!