# Subsetting rows inside function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to subset rows of a data.table programatically inside an R function. The following works as expected:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, variable = c("test","data","data", "is", "fun"))
dt[variable == "data"]
```

```
   id variable
1:  2     data
2:  3     data
```

If I define the function:

```
dtSubset <- function(df, col, str) {
  df[col == str]
}
dtSubset(df, "variable", "data")
```

I get a 0-row table.

The following works:

```
dtSubset <- function(df, str) {
  dt[variable == str]
}
dtSubset(df, "data")
```

so the issue lies with selecting the column inside the function.

I tried combinations of `eval`, `substitute`, `quote` and `deparse`, quoting and unquoting the column name to be passed in, each to no avail. I also tried out `subset` but ran into the same issues. 
The vignettes describe how to do this in `j` but not in `i`. Not sure if I've missed something obvious or whether I'm just thinking wrong, but how should I be going about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `get` to make your function work:

```
dtSubset <- function(df, col, str) {
  df[get(col) == str]
}
```

Now `dtSubset(dt, "variable", "data")` will get you the intended result:

> ```
>    id variable
> 1:  2     data
> 2:  3     data
> ```

Comment: `get` was the part that I had missed. Ended up doing a `deparse(substitute(col))` and `get` so the column can be provided unquoted. Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass quoted variable in the function you could subset columns using `[[`

```
dtSubset <- function(df, col, str) {
     df[df[[col]] == str, ]
}

dtSubset(dt, "variable", "data")

#   id variable
#1:  2     data
#2:  3     data
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried combinations of `eval`, `substitute`, `quote` and `deparse`, quoting and unquoting the column name to be passed in, each to no avail.

You can do

```
subit <- function(d, cc, vv){
  ex = substitute( d[cc == vv], list(cc = as.name(cc), vv = vv) )
  print(ex)
  eval(ex)
}

subit(dt, "variable", "data")

d[variable == "data"]
   id variable
1:  2     data
2:  3     data
```

`as.name` or `as.symbol` takes the quotes off `"variable"`.

With this approach, you can take advantage of data.tables optimized "auto indexing". @sindri_baldur's answer also uses indices by creating one and joining. A third alternative would be on-the-fly joining:

```
jit <- function(d, cc, vv) d[.(unique(vv)), on=cc, nomatch=0]
jit(dt, "variable", "data")
```

Some alternatives for this "subsetting join" are here: [Perform a semi-join with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18969420)

Answer (score 1):

One more option is using `setkey()` inside the function:

```
dtSubset <- function(df, col, str) {
  setkeyv(df, col)[str]
}

dtSubset(dt, "variable", "data")
#    id variable
# 1:  2     data
# 2:  3     data
```